# Android Freezes when making SQLiteOpenHelper calls from AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

If I have an SQLiteOpenHelper class with methods that I use to insert objects into my DB, if I make calls to this method from inside an AsyncTask, will the calls to the DB be done on a separate thread or in the main UI thread?

I would think that the DB calls would be made on the background thread. Am I understanding the asynctask class incorrectly? Would I have to rewrite all my DB calls inside my SQLiteOpenHelper to use asynctasks?

Currently, I'm getting a lot of lag on my android device and a message that says:

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I'm making calls to a webservice which responds with a json string which I'm parsing inside my doinbackground method and then inserting items into a DB.

```
public class DB_Async {
public void replaceDeck(String jsonString, Delegate d){
    ReplaceDeck del = new ReplaceDeck();
    del.setDelegate(d);
    del.addParameter("json", jsonString);
    del.execute();
}
private class ReplaceDeck extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

    private Delegate delegate;
    private Exception error;
    private Hashtable<String, String> parameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    public void setDelegate(Delegate d){
        delegate = d;
    }

    public void addParameter(String key, String value){
        parameters.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {                     //Main Thread
        super.onPreExecute();

        if(delegate != null)
            delegate.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       //Main Thread
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(delegate != null)
            delegate.onResult(result, error);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params){  //BACKGROUND THREAD
        String currDate = new Date().toString();
        SQLdataHelper mDataHelper = SQLdataHelper.getInstance();
        String result = null;
        String jsonString = parameters.get("json");
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj    = new JSONObject(jsonString);    
            JSONArray  jsonDecks = jsonObj.getJSONArray("decks");   
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonDecks.length(); i++){
                Deck newDeck = new Deck();
                int new_deck_id =  mDataHelper.addDeck(newDeck); // call to SQLOpenHelper
            }           
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            result = e.getMessage();
            error = e;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

My DB just inserts a new row into my Decks Column:

```
 public synchronized long addDeck(Deck deck){
    String currDate = new Date().toString();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_DECK_UID_COLUMN, deck.student_id);
    values.put(DB_DECK_NAME_COLUMN, deck.name);
    values.put(DB_DECK_DESC_COLUMN, deck.description);
    values.put(DB_DECK_DIFFICULTY_COLUMN, deck.difficulty);
    values.put(DB_DECK_COUNT_COLUMN, deck.cardCount);
    values.put(DB_DECK_RATING_COLUMN, deck.rating);
    values.put(DB_DECK_CREATED_COLUMN, currDate);
    values.put(DB_DECK_UPDATED_COLUMN, currDate);
    values.put(DB_DECK_WEBID_COLUMN, deck.web_id);
    values.put(DB_DECK_NEED_SYNC, 0);
    long deck_id = mDB.insert(DB_DECK_TABLE, null, values);
    return deck_id;
}
```

To Call this method, I create a new delegate and call my ReplaceDeck.

```
DB_Async.Delegate asyncDelegate = new DB_Async.Delegate() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onResult(String result, Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Successful Download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    try{
        DB_Async bf = new DB_Async(mContext);
        bf.replaceDeck(jsonString, asyncDelegate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: When you profiled your app in Traceview, to find out really what is going wrong, what did you learn?

Comment: Never heard of Traceview until now. Thanks for the tip! I'll check it out now

Answer (score 0):

> i'm making calls to a webservice which responds with a json string
>   which I'm parsing inside my doinbackground method and then inserting
>   items into a DB.

means you are trying to make webservice call on UI Thread then passing it to `replaceDeck` as parameter to start `AsyncTask` and parse it inside doinbackground .

you also need to put webservice calling related code inside doinbackground method of AsyncTask . for this you can use two AsyncTask's one for making call to webservice to get data and second for inserting data in DB.